# Whats the use of GetLowerBound()?

Tags: vb.net

The lowerbound of an array is always zero in VB.net, even if the first element is set to `Nothing`. So why do we need to use GetLowerBound(`dimension`) to get the index of the first element of an array in a particular dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per documentation found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=net-6.0

There can be arrays that do not start with index 0:

> Note that, although most arrays in .NET are zero-based (that is, the
> GetLowerBound method returns zero for each dimension of an array),
> .NET does support arrays that are not zero-based. Such arrays can be
> created with the CreateInstance(Type, Int32[], Int32[]) method, and
> can also be returned from unmanaged code.